# pgf(plots) node shadow/opaque pin

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes, transparency

Is it possible to place a `shadow`/`fill`/`opaque` setting on *text* of a node `pin`? I know I can do that with the actual node, but I am using `\node` in `pgfplots` to mark some stuff on graphs, and it would be great if I could make a white filling in the text area to make it more clear.
Of course, if you know a better way to achieve the same thing in `pgf`, let me know.

Code I've got so far is below. I tried putting something like `[opaque=0.5]` after `pin`, but it seems it has no such options, and I wasn't able to find anything relevant to `pin` text in `pgf` documentation.

```
\tikzset{small dot/.style={fill=black,
                           circle,scale=0.2}}

\node[small dot, pin=120:{$100\ k\Omega$}] at (axis description cs:0.5,0.61) {};
```

Comment: Did you try `opacity=0.5`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get a semi-transparent background for your pin (or any other node, for that matter), you first need to specify some fill colour. So to get a semi-opaque node background, you could set `fill=white, fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1`. Note that the `text opacity` needs to be set separately, since `fill opacity` applies both to the background colour and the text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,
    grid=both, minor tick num=3, grid style=gray % Darker grid than normal to show the effect better
]
\node[pin={[fill=white, fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1]120:$100\ k\Omega$}] at (axis description cs:0.5,0.6) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

I have been using `\tikzset{every pin/.style={draw=black,fill=yellow!10}}` which yields:

[image]

### Note:

- The `!10` notation decreases the intensity of the color. See [the `xcolor` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor) for more details.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{small dot/.style={fill=black, circle,scale=0.2}}
\tikzset{every pin/.style={draw=black,fill=yellow!10}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1]
\node[small dot, pin=120:{$100\ k\omega$}] at (axis description cs:0.5,0.61) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a really great idea.