# pgfplots pins in front of the axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I wish to draw two pins on a plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot {x^2} node[pos=1,pin={[pin distance=0.5em, rounded corners, red, draw=red, fill=red!10!white]20:{$c$}}] {}
  node[pos=0.8,pin={[pin distance=0.5em, rounded corners, red, draw=red, fill=red!10!white]20:{$c$}}] {};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the top-right pin is behind the axes and therefore is clipped and partially unreadable. Is there a way to alter the z-axis ordering of the nodes so that the pin is in front of the rest of the image and thus is not cropped?

Comment: A quick fix is to give the option `clip=false` but if your plot extends beyond the axis limits it's not good enough. A better approach is to put the TikZ commands inside the `after end axis/.code`. There must be a recent question about this but I couldn't retrieve it.... Here it is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119821/placing-text-inside-graphs-using-pgfplot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add option `clip=false` to `axis` and will see a complete `pin`. Your top pin is not `behind` the axes but just `partially outside`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[clip=false]
  \addplot {x^2} node[pos=1,pin={[pin distance=0.5em, rounded corners, red, draw=red, fill=red!10!white]20:{$c$}}] {}
  node[pos=0.8,pin={[pin distance=0.5em, rounded corners, red, draw=red, fill=red!10!white]20:{$c$}}] {};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]